# error : Version 5.0.10 0-alpha1-014696 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

I am trying to build ASP.NET Core Source code locally. As per the instruction mentioned on https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/docs/BuildFromSource.md, when i execute

> .\restore.cmd

i am getting below error

> error : Version 5.0.100-alpha1-014696 of the .NET Core SDK requires at
>   least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of
>   MSBuild is 16.0.461.62831. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in
>   global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version
>   currently available.

I have Windows 10 Pro 1903 and Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.3.5 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have run `./eng/scripts/InstallVisualStudio.ps1` to ensure you have the tools required.

Next make sure you enable the option to use previews of the .NET Core SDK in VS2019:

> Tools > Options and check Use previews of the .NET Core SDK under
>   Environment > Preview Features

And yes, I agree, the fact that a setting in VS IDE alters a command-line build is surprising and it seems to be a common error when trying to build the source to miss this setting.

Close Visual Studio and rerun .\restore.cmd

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have performed the above steps but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you run msbuild /version from a developer command prompt what do you get?

Comment: I am getting msbuild version as 16.3.2.50909 when executed in developer command prompt

Comment: Executing the .\restore.cmd command in developer command prompt worked. Able to build the project. I was executing this command in separate CMD session. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @manojkulkarni30 That worked for me as well, thanks! You should post that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Was trying to solve this issue for a month - I didn't realize you had to run . .\activate.ps1 first, then attempt to build.